# UriMatcher won't match

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I created URI as `content://com.freshfase.provider.MBoardGetDetailProvider/mboard_get_student_by_section_detail/a/b`

by using:

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.withAppendedPath(MBoardGetDetailProvider.GET_STUDENT_DETAIL_BY_SECTION_URI, "a");
Uri uri2 = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri1, "b");
```

In my `ContentProvider` I use:

```
public static final int GET_STUDENT_DETAIL_BY_SECTION = 5;
public static final Uri GET_STUDENT_DETAIL_BY_SECTION_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/mboard_get_student_by_section_detail");
uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "mboard_get_student_by_section_detail/*/*", GET_STUDENT_DETAIL_BY_SECTION);
```

And while calling:

```
int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
```

I expect the `uriType` value as 5 but it returns `-1`.